# Bypassing a 17S lithium battery pack, can I use 17S BMS with a 16S battery pack?

Tags: lithium-ion, battery-chemistry

I have 60 V lithium battery with 17 series.
In this one series damaged.

I bypassed the damaged series and tried using the same 17S BMS (by ignoring the *last* wire).
But it didn't work.

Looks the BMS requires a voltage in the range 2.9 and 4.2 V between consecutive wires.

So, to fool the BMS, I put one fully charged lithium cell between battery positive terminal and BMS *last* wire.
Now the BMS is working fine as it is seeing proper voltages across all series.

Will this work around cause any problems?

---

As per datasheet:

[image]

I modified it to:

[image]

Comment: That's how I would do it. Does it do balancing? If yes, you may have issues.

Comment: @winny yes the BMS  does a very basic balancing. datasheet says  when a series goes above 4.25V, the bms  will discharge the series to 4.20V.  let me know if you want to see the datasheet.. ill upload... also how long a single lithium cell maintain the voltage ?  because BMS will draw current from the single cell right?

Comment: Depends, if it’s discharge only for balancing triggered by cell voltage alone, probably not much will happen. If it’s redistribution of charge (“inductive BMS” = half-bridge with inductor across each pair of batteries), then your single cell gangling there may be subject to discharge and trip the BMS.